# Can't upload file to phalcon app

Tags: file-upload, image-uploading, phalcon

```
public function profilePictureAction()
    {
        // Check if the user has uploaded files
        if ($this->request->hasFiles()) {

            // Print the real file names and sizes
            foreach ($this->request->getUploadedFiles() as $file) {

                // Print file details
                echo $file->getName(), " ", $file->getSize(), "\n";

                // Move the file into the application
                $file->moveTo('files/' . $file->getName());

            }
        }
}
```

Above is the code using phalcon framework to upload image using form-data. I already test this code with postman but there is a problem.
it's output is icon-testing.png 6773
image name and image size
but file not uploaded to files folder.
already try using full path of my linux ubuntu /var/www/html/myapp/files
still can't upload.
already chmod 755 files folder
and chown :www-data and chown my-username that html folder.
If this is because bad permissions I want to know how to solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: `moveto()` returns a boolean for operation result. Try to `var_dump` it and see if it is ok.

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov its ok.. i found out that folder access must give access read and write in order to upload to other user. thank you..

Comment: So your problem is fixed and it was permissions problem? If it is so answer your question or even close it so others don't waste time to test and answer it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Solved with changing Others Access: can create and delete files.